# objective c - after picking image from gallery or camera - needs to enable rotate, flip editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

After picking the image from gallery or camera - needs to enable rotate, flip editing How can i acive that.Here my code :

```
-(void)photofromCamera
{

    @try
    {
         NSLog(@"2");
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {

        [self showAlert:@"Camera is not available"];
    }

}



-(void)photofromGallery
{

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

So after the delegate method :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self.imageDeletionButton setHidden:NO];
    UIImage *chosenImage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
     self.PostImageView.image = chosenImage;
     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

As if now, if i pick any image from gallery, camera - i needs to show the crop, flip, rotation.please help me out how can i achive that.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: FYI - Get rid of the `try/catch`. That is not the proper way to handle the camera not being available. Use `UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable`.

Comment: @rmaddy  sure, but how can i get the flip, rotate option is it possibe ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the swift based framework IGRPhotoTweaks for rotate, flip and crop the image.
You can check the https://github.com/IGRSoft/IGRPhotoTweaks for git and
https://cocoapods.org/pods/IGRPhotoTweaks for cocoapods.
In the framework `cropAction()` and `changedAngel(value: radians)` are the 2 methods that you need to try to achieve your requirement.